# is it possible to verify certificate chain using openssl while skipping the expiry date

Tags: openssl, x509certificate

We are working with [AWS Nitro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/enclaves/latest/user/set-up-attestation.html) , which provides a certificate only for 3 hours .

We are looking for a way where we can skip the expiry part in verification and still confirm the certificate chain is valid.

Comment: NB: full documentation on -attime behaviour can be found https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-verification-options.html search for **-attime**

Answer (score 1):

According to openssl-verify docs

```
       -attime timestamp
           Perform validation checks using time specified by timestamp and not current system time. timestamp is the number of seconds since 01.01.1970 (UNIX time).
```

If you specify the flag's value to sometime before the expiry it'll help you skip the expiry check as it'll always return true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-days` option with `x509` command .

Eg:

```
openssl x509 -days
```

I am not sure -days work with `openssl req` because validity determines `x509`.

Answer (score 0):

To suppress checking the expiration date on a certificate, use the [`X509_V_FLAG_NO_CHECK_TIME`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/X509_VERIFY_PARAM_get_inh_flags.html) flag:

```
X509_STORE_set_flags (store, other_flags | X509_V_FLAG_NO_CHECK_TIME);
```

> The `X509_V_FLAG_NO_CHECK_TIME` flag suppresses checking the validity period of certificates and CRLs against the current time.

There doesn't seem to be a way to set this option on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

For `openssl` the flag is `-no_check_time`

e.g. to verify that certA.pem is issued by certB.pem you normally use:

**Not using the flag:**

```
openssl verify -no-CAfile -no-CApath -partial_chain -trusted "certA.pem" "certB.pem"
```

output:

```
error 10 at 0 depth lookup: certificate has expired  
error certA.pem: verification failed
```

**Using the flag:**

```
openssl verify -no_check_time -no-CAfile -no-CApath -partial_chain -trusted "certA.pem" "certB.pem"
```

output with the flag:

```
certA.pem: OK
```